# Название полей таблиц

Tags: postgresql, база-данных, mysql

Подскажите, в каком виде лучше записывать название полей в бд?
Например, есть поле `catId`. Как считаете, не лучше ли его назвать `cat_id` ?
Есть ли какие-то стандарты и своеобразные правила к записи названий полей?

З.Ы. понимаю, что вопрос странный и, наверное, в какой-то мере глупый, но всё же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В то время, как в коде принято называть переменные в виде camelCase, в таблицах используется наименование вида cat_id, type_id и подобное.

Соответственно, лучше называть поля с "_" и не использовать заглавных букв - так будет проще поддерживать и разрабатывать код.

Answer (score 2):

Дело вкуса. Я лично придерживаюсь [таких правил](https://www.reg.ru/coding_standards#sql) (раздел 10: SQL, базы данных)

P.S. С [reg.ru](http://reg.ru) никак не связан, и по остальным пунктам - не всё разделяю :)

Comment: 10.5 и 10.6 - спорно, а всё остальное - да, по делу